# How do I increase the speed of my website?

Tags: html, css, performance

I built a website that is currently live at this link [Arema Insurance Agency](https://aremainsurance.com/)

The issue is it takes too long to load the png images I have on there. Most of the body of the website was designed in adobe illustrator and imported as a png.  The size of the homepage png is 4.4 MB and ( width="1892" height="3082" ) in my html.

Is there a way I can optimize the speed?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of options here.

1. Optimise the images. Run them through an online compressor like [Squoosh](https://squoosh.app/).
2. Cache the website. How to do this is highly dependent on how the site is set up. Considering the site is made up of just three images (incredibly bad-practice by the way), I'd guess your setup probably isn't equipped for this.
3. Get better hosting. It shouldn't take 20 seconds to load a 4.4mb webpage, I suspect your hosting service is terrible. Sticking to the big players such as [CrazyDomains](https://www.crazydomains.com.au/) or [HostGator](https://www.hostgator.com/) is your best bet.

There's plenty of other ways detailed on Google, but start with these as they are the easiest and most likely to have an effect on a site like this.

Comment: Thanks @harryburk, the online compressor worked very well and now my site is much faster. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer tools from your browser and check the network section of that(similar to where you check console.log statement)

In Chrome to open network tab ***ctrl+shift+i*** and then network. It will open this up

As far as I inspected your ***HomePageOfficial_AIA.png***  is taking more time to load. So you can optimize the image accordingly or check your hosting support for the same
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cxR7.png